# Bathtub decals peeling off in short time

Tags: bathroom

Our tub decals are only about a month new, and are already starting to peel off.  Is there something I can do about this?

[image]

Comment: What are bathtub decals?

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j10c4.jpg)

Comment: It would be hard to say without knowing what the decals are made of. They look like stickers to me, but its hard to tell. Could you tell us what they are made of? Thanks!

Comment: @SusanMilillo Much more information is appreciated like picture of a peeling off. Also do share us information about its material type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't advocate against using a lifehack, but be wary of using anything that would make these decals truly permanent. While there are definitely ways to keep these from coming up, they might work so well that if you went to sell your house/get your security deposit back on your apartment you could get stuck paying for a new bath tub if there is residue left behind.

...Perhaps you would better off financially in the long run simply buying higher quality tub decals...

Source: I own and am renovating fixer upper, and permanent bathroom decorations knocked 5 figures off the house price.

Answer (score 0):

Use silicon based caulk when the tub is dry to glue the decals back on. Or any tub-caulk in fact. Home depot or Lowes or local hardware. Get a small tube.